# Unable to do bitwise OR operation on int field mysql query

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, or-operator

**In brief**

Suppose an `int` type field in my table contains any binary four digit number (combination of 0s and 1s, e.g. 1010, 0110 etc.). How do I selectively update only some of those digits without changing the others.

**Details**
I have a `user_relevance_code` field in my `permissions` table (which is of type `int(10)`) which stores four digits which represents which account types this particular permission is relevant to. These four digits store a 1 or 0 each meaning whether or not it is relevant. From left to right, the relevance to these account types - `Manager`, `Publisher`, `Advertiser`, `Developer` is stored. So, a value `0110` stored in this field would mean it is relevant to Managers, Publishers and not relevant to Advertisers.

Now, at any point of time, suppose I need to mark some of these permissions as relevant to managers, or make them relevant to advertisers and publishers and at the same time make them not relevant to managers, and all such random operations. For all such cases, I need to keep the other digits untouched. This means, if I need to update the manager relevance digit only, I should not touch the publisher and advertiser digits.

**Problem**
It is obvious that I need to do binary OR of the code I need to apply with the current value of `user_relevance_code` and store it, but this is not working for me.

For the operation of making some permissions relevant to publishers, I tried this query -

```
update permissions set user_relevance_code = (0100 | user_relevance_code) where <condition to update some permissions>
```

But this did not produce desired results. Those records which were having `1000` earlier, got updated to `1004`, where I wanted them to become `1100` (update only the 2nd digit to 1 and leave others as they are).

I also tried changing the type of that field to `binary`. I guess I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `0100` is a decimal number, not a base-2 number, that's why you're getting 1004 for `100 | 1000`. If you want to ensure that the 2<sup>2</sup> bit is set then you want this:

```
user_relevance_code = b'100' | user_relevance_code
```

or, if you prefer to specify all four bits for clarity (a good idea when bit wrangling):

```
user_relevance_code = b'0100' | user_relevance_code
```

All of the above does assume that you really are storing bitmaps in your `user_relevance_code` rather than base-10 numbers (such as 1000, 1101, 110, ...) that just happen to look like binary. If the values really are decimal, then bit operations aren't the best tool for the job and you'd probably want to use something unpleasant like this:

```
user_relevance_code = (user_relevance_code div 1000) * 1000 + 100 + (user_relevance_code % 100)
```

to force the 10<sup>2</sup> digit to be a 1 while leaving the other three alone.

I have to say that bit wrangling really isn't a natural thing to be doing in SQL. A separate (user, permission) association table would be a lot more natural. Then you'd manipulate the permission sets with simple joins, inserts, and deletes. Of course, if you don't have control over the schema then you have to go with what you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, but `select (b'0100' | user_relevance_code) from ox_permissions where user_relevance_code = 1000` also shows `1004` and `update ox_permissions set user_relevance_code = (b'1000' | user_relevance_code) where user_relevance_code = 1000` does not do the update. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: @Sandeepan: `where user_relevance_code = 1000` uses a decimal value. What does your table actually look like? And what does the data really look like? Is `user_relevance_code` actually a bitmap?